# Error messages all over my project after changing source files in modules

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I imported a project from github. First I would get Migrate to Android message so I imported it accordingly and changed my source files in modules under project structure. Now my files are filled with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **Project > clean** 
Then clean your current project.
I hope that the problem will be solved if there is no error in code. 
You can also restart the IDE to resolve the errors.

Comment: Click on Build Tab on top of Toolbar , and then select the Clean Project option. That might solve your purpose.